# What type of Prometheus metrics we can use if we need to store max value at a given time?

Tags: prometheus

I have to use Prometheus metrics for following type of measurement, I don't want to store/compare last updated data. I just want to use Prometheus api, which should take care of checking the value and either update/ignores the value.  What type of metrics I can classify for this?

```
if(value > measResultsRtpPerformance.maxDlJit)
{
    measResultsRtpPerformance.maxDlJit = value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus stores data as time series of values not single values like max.

This is because it enables the calculation of e.g. the max value yesterday, in the last hour, in the last 5 minutes.

The only way, it can do this is by calculating e.g. max on demand by using some user-defined subset of all the time series data it contains.

You can use, [Counters, Gauges, Histograms and Summaries](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/). That's it. In your case, I suspect you want to use a Gauge to measure the values. Gauges record values that may go up and down.

You can then use [PromQL](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/) to calculate e.g. `max_over_time` for any subset of the time series that you've data.